# Sum of one array compared to uniques of another

Tags: list-manipulation

This might be a basic question, but it has me stumped. I have two arrays, and I wish to output the uniques of the first and sum of the respective components of the second

Input

```
Xin = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}};
Yin = {n[1], n[2], n[3], n[4], n[5], n[6], n[7], n[8]}
```

Output:

```
Xout = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}
Yout = {n[1], n[2] + n[4] + n[6] + n[7] + n[8], n[3], n[5]}
```

I know `Xout=DeleteDuplicates[Xin]`, but can't figure out how to determine `Yout` (for general Xin and Yin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Merge`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Merge.html):

```
Values @ Merge[Total] @ Thread[Xin -> Yin]
```

> {n[1], n[2] + n[4] + n[6] + n[7] + n[8], n[3], n[5]}

Alternatively, you can use [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html):

```
Values @ GroupBy[Thread[{Xin, Yin}], First -> Last, Total]
```

> {n[1], n[2] + n[4] + n[6] + n[7] + n[8], n[3], n[5]}

Further alternatives:

```
Map[Total[Yin[[#]]] &] @ Values @ PositionIndex[Xin]
```

> {n[1], n[2] + n[4] + n[6] + n[7] + n[8], n[3], n[5]}

or

```
Values @ Map[Total[Yin[[#]]] &] @ PositionIndex[Xin]
```

> {n[1], n[2] + n[4] + n[6] + n[7] + n[8], n[3], n[5]}

Answer (score 1):

The resource function ["GroupByList"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/GroupByList) seems well suited for this problem:

```
ResourceFunction["GroupByList"][Yin, Xin, Total]
Values @ %
```

> <|{0, 0} -> n[1], {1, 1} -> n[2] + n[4] + n[6] + n[7] + n[8], {1, 0} -> 
>     n[3], {0, 1} -> n[5]|>
>
> {n[1], n[2] + n[4] + n[6] + n[7] + n[8], n[3], n[5]}